# sql yielding double values in double select query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT
a.url,
b.lpvs,
a.volume,
a.sales_usd,
a.sales_eur,
a.sales_gbp,
a.sales_jpy
FROM (
SELECT
referer_trackings.cookie_first_url AS url,
count(purchases.id) AS volume,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.currency = 'USD' THEN purchases.price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_usd,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.currency = 'EUR' THEN purchases.price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_eur,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.currency = 'GBP' THEN purchases.price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_gbp,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.currency = 'JPY' THEN purchases.price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_jpy
FROM purchases
JOIN referer_trackings 
ON referer_trackings.trackable_id = purchases.id
JOIN items
ON purchases.item_id = items.id
WHERE items.seller_id = '6'
AND referer_trackings.trackable_type = 'Purchase'
AND purchases.workflow_state = 'payment_successful'
GROUP BY referer_trackings.cookie_first_url
ORDER BY volume DESC
) AS a, (SELECT
count(referer_trackings.id) AS lpvs
FROM referer_trackings
JOIN product_landing_page_views
ON product_landing_page_views.id = referer_trackings.trackable_id
JOIN items
ON items.id = product_landing_page_views.item_id
WHERE referer_trackings.trackable_type = 'ProductLandingPageView'
AND items.seller_id = '6')
AS b
```

This yield this result:

```
url    lpvs    volume    sales_usd    sales_eur   sales_gbp   sales_jpy
=======================================================================

url1   1082    3         9.99         9.99        9.99        0.0
url2   1082    1         0.0          9.99        0.0         0.0
        ^
```

The second row of the lpvs column (value: 1082, with the little arrow below) should be 0, not 1082. Value 1082 is only correct for the first row.

I know this is due to some doubling when joining/selecting but I cant seem to get my head around undoubling this and getting the query just right.

I can just call two queries from my ruby code and merge the results. That would be the quick solution. However, I would like to keep this clean and go for a pure sql solution. I feel i'm very close.

If someone knows how to do this using ActiveRecord that would be great as well :-).

Thanks for your time!

===== EDIT =====

Based on Rahul's tweaks this is the result of the query:

```
url    lpvs    volume    sales_usd    sales_eur   sales_gbp   sales_jpy
=======================================================================

url1   7       7         19.98        29.97       19.98       0.0
url2   1       1         0.0          9.99        0.0         0.0
       ^       ^         ^            ^           ^

^1, row 1 => value should be 1082
^1, row 2 => value should be 0
^2, row 1 => value should be 3
^2, row 2 => value should be 1
^3, row 1 => value should be 9.99 (current value is doubled somehow)
^4, row 1 => value should be 9.99 (current value is tripled somehow)
^5, row 1 => value should be 9.99 (current value is doubled somehow)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of your spurious below query part which I am not sure why you are doing ...

```
....
ORDER BY volume DESC
) AS a, (SELECT
count(referer_trackings.id) AS lpvs
FROM referer_trackings
........)
AS b
```

In your main select you are saying

```
SELECT
a.url,
b.lpvs, <-- result of above posted query part
```

Yes, modify your entire query to be like below

```
SELECT
referer_trackings.cookie_first_url AS url,
count(referer_trackings.id) AS lpvs,
count(purchases.id) AS volume,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.currency = 'USD' THEN purchases.price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_usd,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.currency = 'EUR' THEN purchases.price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_eur,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.currency = 'GBP' THEN purchases.price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_gbp,
SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.currency = 'JPY' THEN purchases.price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_jpy

FROM purchases
LEFT JOIN referer_trackings ON referer_trackings.trackable_id = purchases.id
AND referer_trackings.trackable_type IN ('Purchase', 'ProductLandingPageView')
LEFT JOIN product_landing_page_views ON product_landing_page_views.id = referer_trackings.trackable_id
LEFT JOIN items ON purchases.item_id = items.id AND items.seller_id = '6'

WHERE purchases.workflow_state = 'payment_successful'
GROUP BY referer_trackings.cookie_first_url
ORDER BY volume DESC;
```

Comment: Are you saying that the desired results are possible without the second query?

Comment: Thanks :-). However, your query makes the values of the lpvs column exactly the same as the volume column... Value 1082 for lpvs was correct, but only for the first row, not the second.

Comment: I copied your query. See my edits in original question